# mess up with ng-repeat and ng-options?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

This question may have already an answer. But I have seen so many users are posting questions regarding `ng-repeat` and `ng-options` as they are not able to achieve the desired solution.

There are lot of questions on `ng-repeat` and `ng-options` but users with their data that is coming as a response from a request, they are making it complicated or already it is complicated and then posting their question on the site.

Can someone please tell these two things(`ng-repeat` and `ng-options`) in detail with brief explanation and best cases? Why can't we simplify the data in the controllers before coming in to the view level to reduce `looping`?

Comment: I'm confused.  You say answer "two things" but I only see one question that follows.  My answer to the first would be: you absolutely can simplify data before bringing it to the view.  I do in all my angular projects.

Comment: I see you updated your question but I'm still confused.  Are you asking about what function they server and what reasons you would use `ng-repeat` and `ng-options`?  I'm not sure what you mean by "best cases".

Comment: You seem to be asking why there are many questions here about ng-repeat and ng-options. That's off-topic. If your question is how to use them, then you should simply read their documentation. My personal optinion is that there would be much less questions about them if people read their documentation, with care.